# Change colour of conditionally formatted cells to real colour

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, fill

I have an Excel sheet with conditionally formatted cells with different conditions.  I need the initial colour of the conditional formatting to stay, although the value is going to change in the following calculations.

My solution atm is manual selection and filling of the cells. Is there a possibility to automate this?

Here is a screenshot of part of the excel sheet [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3ePL.png

Comment: `Conditional Formatting` gives you the option to colour the cells so not sure what you mean by **real colour**?

Comment: Hey Zac, the thing with conditional formatting is that the colour changes depending on the values in the cell - which is its functionality. I need to colour cells with conditional formatting and then be able to change the values, while the colour stays the same. Rorys code works really well for that on my excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
Sub fixCF_Formatting()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim CF_range As Range
    Set CF_range = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllFormatConditions)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not CF_range Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In CF_range
        If cell.Interior.Color <> cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color Then _
                        cell.Interior.Color = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Next cell
    ' remove the CF if desired
    CF_range.FormatConditions.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

If you want to leave the CF rules in place, comment out the Delete line at the end.

Comment: Thank you Rory, that worked really well!